# Pulling a div within an H1 tag to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a header, and then I have a div within that header. The header's text displays on the left, as it should. However, I would like the div to appear on the same line as the header but pulled to the right. What is the css I should use to achieve this? Thank you!

```
<h1 id="header">
  Text
  <div class="headerDiv">
  </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: Please edit the post with your current code.

Comment: What have to tried so far? `float:right`?

Comment: I don't think `<div>` is a valid child of `<h1>`.

Comment: `<h3><div>header</div>text for h3</h3>`, then `div { float: right }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation might work, but is not recommended.
I would suggest have the div outside your header. If need be, you can always encapsulate these inside a main wrapper div.

```
<h1 style="float:left;">Some Text</h1>
<div style="float:right; width:100px; height:50px; background:#CCC;"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Here is an example to look at: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6hqkwy6/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<h1>
  <span>Some Text</span>
  <div>Some Div</div>
</h1>

h1 > span {
  float: left;
}

h1 > div {
  float: right;
}
```

Doing so you should also be adding a clearfix to the `h1`:

```
h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```